# Принудительно обновить страницу после POST-запроса

Tags: php, javascript

Есть обработчик для добавления комментария:

```
if (isset($_POST['CommentEnter']))
{
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $mark = $_POST['mark'];
    $idproduct = $params[1];
    $text = stripslashes($text);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    $text = trim($text);
    $add = new Model_Product();
    $add->add_comment($idproduct,$text, $mark);
}
```

Так вот после добавления комментария хотелось бы принудительно перезагрузить страницу, чтобы добавленный коммент стал виден, как это сделать?

Comment: ну если никаких заголовков еще не выводилось в output, то `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;`...http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-description... если уже все было то `echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.example.com/'; </script>";` ...... а вообще в современном мире делается уже все через `ajax` без перезагрузки.... то есть надо через аякс послать запрос на сервер, тот вернет значение, а на клиенте уже скрипт добавит запись в DOM

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, надеялся без ajax разобраться, так как в нем я пока что 0, но видимо придется с помощью него реализовывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
if (isset($_POST['CommentEnter']))
{
    $text=$_POST['text'];
    $mark=$_POST['mark'];
    $idproduct = intval($params[1]);
    $text = stripslashes($text);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    $text = trim($text);
    $add = new Model_Product();
    $add->add_comment($idproduct,$text, $mark);

    header('Location: /ru/product/details/' . $idproduct);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: подскажите, у меня адрес имеет вид типа "http://www.ru/product/details/3", где цифра 3 хранится в переменной, как мне правильно записать эту ссылку в header?

Comment: @Денис поправил ответ